# Unable to load css file in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and trying to learn it but i am unable to load or use my css stylesheet for layout. The method i followed to load CSS file is what i found on internet but it did not worked. Please suggest something.

**Here is my code**:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>homePage</title>

 <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
    img, div { behavior: url(http('<?php echo $base_url; ?>images') }
    </style>
<![endif]-->


<!--[IF lte IE 6]>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->
</head>

 <body >


 <div id="page">
 <div id="menulinks">
    <a class="active" href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
</div>
<div id="header">

</div>
          <div class="active" id="contentarea">
  <br>
 <br> 
 </div>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where did you place your css files?

Comment: my css files are in my www/codeiginitor/res/css/style.css

Comment: res folder and css folder are made by me and i placed my style sheet in it . and in view file i wrote like this.                         <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[IF lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This is a comment and most browsers will not parse what is inside. It is usable only under IE. You need to put `<link>` outside the comments:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: i have written this tag like this now in my view file .. still it did not work  . my css file is in :                                                                     www/codeignitor/res/css/homestyle.css                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />

Comment: It must be something with the path. try with / at the beginning `href="/res/css/homestyle.css"`

Comment: now my css style is loaded but im not able to see my background images. my images are in css file.                                   #header {

width:900px;
height:119px;
background-image:url(/images/header.png);
padding-top:70px;
padding-bottom:8px;
padding-right:-20px;
}                                                                         but they are not being loaded.. images folder is placed in www/codeignitor/images              where i am wrong

Comment: image path must be relative to the css position. If css file is `ww/codeignitor/res/css/` and images in `ww/codeignitor/images` that means the relative path from css files is `../../images/` and it should look like this: `background-image:url(../../images/header.png);`

Comment: i'm sorry i did not understand your point... could you plz elaborate?

Comment: where im supposed to place my css and images folder for best efficiency? and do you mean that i should write                        'code' background-image:url(codeiginitor/images/header.png);  my base_url is : http:localhost/codeignitor ---- and index page is: 'code' $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: If you want to use images as backgrounds and define them in css file you must use relative path to those images. If your css file is `www/codeignitor/res/css/homestyle.css` and your image is `www/codeignitor/images/header.png` then you must use `background-image:url(../../images/header.png);`.
Location of the images and css folder has no inpact on efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

HTML wrapped in `<!--[if lte IE 6]>` will only be parsed by IE6 and older - which is great for your behavior attribute, but probably to restrictive for `homestyle.css`. Try this:

```
 <head>
    <title>homePage</title>
    <base href="<?= $base_url;?>">
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <style type="text/css">
            img, div {
                behavior: url(images);
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homestyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

### Edit after your comments:

Well yea, I assumed you had that variable defined from your question. Head into `config/autoload.php` and add the `'url'` key to the `$autoload['helper']` array:

For example: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'your_other_helpers...');`

Then change the above HTML to `<base href="<?= site_url();?>">`

Comment: i tried it but got this error ..                                    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: base_url

Filename: core/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code